# Quicktime Mov with Left Stereo into Mono/Dual Stereo

Tags: macos, quicktime

I recorded a screencast using an external microphone and quicktime.  However, the audio is only on the left channel.  Is there a way via an apple tool, command line, or otherwise to convert a left channel only quicktime movie into mono or copy to both channels?

Answer (score 1):

I use [ffmpegX](http://www.ffmpegx.com/) a lot for transcoding video files from one format to another, there is an option to set audio channels to Mono see the [docs](http://www.ffmpegx.com/audio.html).